# getting RHEL6 kernel code

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, rhel

I want to change some kernel source files for network stack testing so is there any way to get kernel source code for RHEL6 Enterprise edition and how to apply the changes to get results?

Comment: You probably want to install the source version of the linux image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/) from redhat ftp, you may get what you want.

Example:[kernel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.src.rpm](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.src.rpm)

Comment: @akp I do not use rpm. check this using rpm command. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html

Comment: i got!!! thanx... could u please help me how to change some kernel files & then apply them to test results...

Comment: @akp That's nice. If you have problem, you can post it on this site. People are friendly here.

Comment: First you need to install this srpm with `rpm` command, then, find the kernel spec file (probably in ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/), and run `rpmbuild -bp kernel.spec` to get the final source code.

Answer (score 0):

ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/

use CTRL + F to find kernel version that your looking for